# How to correct IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, class, indentation

I'm getting an `IndentationError` with the following

Code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Viraj'
        self.age = 17
        self.dob = 10-1-2003
     def talk(self):
         print("name-", self.name)
         print("age-", self.age)
         print("Date of Birth-", self.dob)

s1=Student()

print(s1.name)
s1.talk()
```

Error message:

```
File "C:/Users/VIRAJ JADHAV/Desktop/College codes in python/data types.py", line 6
    def talk(self):
                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT.

Comment: And please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your title should concisely summarize your question so other users can quickly decide whether they can help or learn from this. We already know you have a problem; you're asking a question on a question and answer site.

Comment: In any case, the issue is exactly what the error message says: your second `def` needs to be outdented by an additional space to match the first `def`. It "doesn't match any outer indentation level". Please remember to search for existing documentation, questions, etc. before asking a new one.

Comment: Side note: `self.dob = 10-1-2003` sets `self.dob` to `-1994` (`10` minus `1` minus `2003`). I think you want `self.dob = "10-1-2003"`, or maybe to use [the `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

The code works well, but you have an extra space on line `def talk(self):`, which impacts the indentation of the code inside this function too.

It should be:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name='Viraj'
        self.age=17
        self.dob=10-1-2003

    def talk(self):
        print("name-", self.name)
        print("age-", self.age)
        print("Date of Birth-", self.dob)

s1=Student()

print(s1.name)
s1.talk()
```